# Given a value, find percentile % with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

There are probably better words to describe this question, however what I am trying to do is the opposite of `np.percentile()`. I have a list of n numbers, and I want to see what percentile of them are smaller than a given value. Right now the way I get this value is by continuously trying different decimals. *What I want* Numpy to tell me is this:

> Given threshold = 0.20 (input), about  99.847781% (output) of the items in list `d` are below this percentile.

What I do right now to get this number is pretty sketchy:

```
>>> np.percentile(np.absolute(d), 99.847781)
0.19999962082827874

>>> np.percentile(np.absolute(d), 99.8477816)
0.19999989822334402

>>> np.percentile(np.absolute(d), 99.8477817)
0.19999994445584851

>>> np.percentile(np.absolute(d), 99.8477818)
0.19999999068835939
...
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(d < given_value) / len(d)`? If you're using `python2` you'd have to cast one of the operands to `float`

Comment: This one? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html#scipy.stats.percentileofscore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like

```
sum(d < threshold) / len(d)
```

should do it.

Edit: I missed the absolute value in the question -

```
sum(np.abs(d) < threshold) / float(len(d))
```

Comment: Edited your code to be python functional, but it was the right idea! I guess I was forgetting the basics! Thanks.

Comment: @cookiedough your edit is not equivalent to what is posted here. If you wanted the absolute value, do `sum(np.absolute(d) < 0.2) / float(len(d))`

Comment: If `d` is a numpy array, the code I gave is valid python code (assuming you're using python3).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `d` is a NumPy array, in general, you can do:

```
(d < threshold).mean()
```

And for absolute values specifically:

```
(np.abs(d) < threshold).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great. But if there's a chance some values in the array could be identical to the threshold (e.g., array of integers), this trick will handle that:

```
( (d < threshold).mean() + (d <= threshold).mean() ) / 2
```

Just averaging using less than and less than or equal to.